# Find an equation that fits closely to these points in 3D space

Tags: polynomials, optimization, regression, plane-curves

I am trying to find an equation $f(x,y) \rightarrow z$ that can be used to return the values in this table, where we'll say the horizontal heading is the $x$ values and the vertical $y$.

[image]

My thinking was to try polynomial fitting, for which I used the 'Solver' add-in in Excel. I started with $f(x, y) = ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx + ey + f$, and the solver tried to optimise the coefficients to make the values as close to the table as possible.

However, it wasn't close enough so I kept increasing the order of the equation, eventually trying $f(x, y) = ax^6 + ... + n$. But I'm still not happy with the accuracy of the equation, given how long it has become.

Are there any better solutions to perform this sort of task? I am not a proficient coder/computational mathematician but from reading up on this it seems using an optimisation programme is the only solution.

This is the results of my attempt:

[image]

UPDATE:

I have added more terms to the polynomial now, and am getting good results. However, the equation is a bit longer than I would hope (see the comment below).

My new question is therefore, what is the best way to find a reasonable solution with as few terms as possible, without trial and error?

[image]

Comment: do you keep all the terms in your polynomials?

Comment: @user619894 Yes, each time I added a new term of higher order I didn't remove any. So last attempt was $ax^6 + by^6 + cx^5 + dx^5 + ... + lx + my + n$.

Comment: I mean, did you keep the cross terms, $x^my^n$ as well?

Comment: @user619894 ah sorry, I am going to add an update. But originally no I hadn't added those, but now have included $... + x^2y + xy^2 + x^3y^2 + x^2y^3$. This has given a much more accurate result, but I do now have an impractically long equation.

Comment: If you have too many parameters, might as well just use the data itself. But maybe you can drop terms with very small coefficients.

Comment: Your best bet for finding a good formula is if you can analyze how these numbers were generated (by physics if these are physical measurements, by financial principles if these are financial measurements, etc.). However if this is not possible, I'd start by looking at finite differences on your columns. the left 4 or 5 columns appear to practically linear with very low slope. Columns 5 and 6 are nearly linear as well, but the slope is increasing. 7 and 8 begin to show some second order increases (quadratic).

Comment: The columns exhibit quadratic behavior at worse, but the rows are a different matter. Their behavior moves from being nearly constant for a long time on the left to showing significantly greater slope on the right. This is not very polynomial behavior, which is why you are getting high degree terms. The row behavior is closer to a rational or exponential function. I suggest trying to fit it to a function of the form$$f(x,y) = a\frac{x + b}{x+c} + d\frac{x + e}{x+f}y + g\frac{x+h}{x+i}y^2$$ where $y$ is the row index. Probably the first term could be constant, and the second nearly so.

Comment: To be more clear, I'd try to start with $f(x,y) = a + by + c\frac{x+d}{x+e}y^2$, and if that isn't sufficient, try allowing the coefficient of $y$ to also be a rational function, etc.